# clone private gitlab repo on docker file using ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, containers

I created a Dockerfile to create an image for a container. I need to clone a private repo on this docker file

I follow this tutorial
https://vsupalov.com/better-docker-private-git-ssh/
I added this steps to my Dockerfile

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone git@gitlab.<my private repo>.git
```

My sshkey on the host is

```
inls ~/.ssh/
id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  known_hosts
```

I try to clone the private repo to the root of the container that will be build with this docker image

update
here is my final docker file

```
FROM python:3.8-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client \
    git \
    && apt-get clean


RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com ~/.ssh/known_hosts


RUN --mount=type=ssh \
    git clone git@gitlab.<org>/<>repo.git
```

and I get this error

```
docker buildx build --ssh default .
[+] Building 0.6s (8/12)                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-bullseye                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-bullseye                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 6.56kB                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends     openssh-client     git     && apt-get clean  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh &&     ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com ~/.ssh/known_hosts                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [4/8] RUN --mount=type=ssh     git clone git@git@gitlab.<org>/<>repo.git                                             0.5s
------                                                                                                                                         
 > [4/8] RUN --mount=type=ssh     git clone git@git@gitlab.<org>/<>repo.git:                                                        
#0 0.299 Cloning into 'the-dock'...
#0 0.432 Host key verification failed.
#0 0.433 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#0 0.433 
#0 0.433 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#0 0.433 and the repository exists.
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git clone git@git@gitlab.<org>/<>repo.git]: exit code: 128
```

Comment: What's the question? Did the tutorial work?

Comment: the tutorial does not work and I can not solve it

Comment: so I question is how can I add the private repo to my docker file

Comment: "the tutorial does not work": do you see an error message?

Comment: I did some changes  
FROM python:3.8-bullseye

#RUN apk update
#RUN apk add git
#RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client
#RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
#RUN --mount=type=ssh \
#  ssh -q -T git@gitlab.com 2>&1 | tee /hello
#RUN --mount=type=ssh
WORKDIR /
RUN --mount=type=ssh  git clone git@gitlab.<my repo>

here is the error 

#0 0.409 Host key verification failed.
#0 0.410 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#0 0.410 
#0 0.410 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#0 0.410 and the repository exists.

Comment: @ibnelhithem Put that information in the question. Comments don't have newlines, so it's hard to read. Include the error message and what changes you made.

Comment: I update the question wih the last update